Firefox v. 130 running ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS opens small window
The only post I can find on this is 12 yrs old. When I open a new Firefox window, it's centered but about half the size of a normal window/what used to be the case. I believe this started after I changed a number of settings re: privacy, following this guide: https://restoreprivacy.com/firefox-privacy/. Anyone else have this problem more recently than 2012? Is the problem and the fix likely the same as it was back then: corrupted localstore.rdf file? If so, will I lose data if I follow the instruction to just delete that file (and Firefox will supposedly generate anew)? TIA.

Please try running firefox with a different profile.  You can create profiles from the command line with the command "firefox -P"  Once created, you can run that profile with the command "firefox -P whatever"  where whatever is the profile just created.

Thanks quill, but I don't entirely understand, and I'd prefer to fix the problem in current profile.

If you know the problem is within your firefox profile then it's not a ubuntu problem.  The moderators of askubuntu.com are sometimes severe about non ubuntu related problems being asked here.  I too have had problems with a firefox profile.  I've unsuccessfully searched for something that will let me compare two firefox profiles.  Mozilla does have a website where questions can be asked (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US).  It's not as easy to use as this one.

Good point, quill, thank you. Yes, I know of that site, which many find frustrating. Thanks much.

Fixed it - when I followed the "restore privacy" steps in the link I posted, I changed privacy.resistFingerprinting to true; I had to change that back to false to get regular-sized windows.
